# Loading cell in table view from xib bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I am loading cell from xib. But then table view controller opens the cell is white. And showing the labes and other stuff only after click on cell.

[image: Like this]

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FixedCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FixedCell"];
    }

    //cellForRow......
    if(indexPath.section==1){
        if(indexPath.row==0){
        FixedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FixedCell"];
        return cell;
       }
   }
```

Can anybody find it, what is wrong here?

Comment: just edit your ques and give some more details so we can understand better and ans accordingly ..

Answer (score 0):

***Objective C***

try this one...

```
cell =(FixedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FixedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height;
}
```

***Swift:***

```
var cell: FixedCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FixedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HistoryTableViewCell

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = FixedCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "FixedCell")
}
```

Comment: I had alredy for this cell:

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 70;
    }
    return 35;
}

And in xib same height

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it may help...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *) willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    FixedCell *newCell = (FixedCell *)cell;
    [newCell layoutIfNeeded];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the `UINib` inside `UITableView` just load it in `viewDidLoad` method..

Use this approach

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FixedCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tablView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FixedCell"];
```